# Simple way to encrypt/decrypt a plaintext in python without imports

Tags: python, python-3.x, encryption

Is there by any chance a way to encrypt/decrypt a plaintext in python without any imports? For example: let's say we have a string that we want to encrypt, inside of a variable or argument named plaintext. We then have another variable or argument where it contains a string where we want to encrypt plaintext into named encrypt_text. Then let's say we have another variable that holds an integer(name this steps), this integer is how many characters left to right we want to place a character from plaintext into encrypt_text. Is this possible?

```
Example: plaintext = "IPHONE"
encrypt_text = "JZIANEUDHCZOANZ"
steps = 3

Final value = "JZIIANEPUDHHCZOOANZNJZIE"
```

Comment: There is, and you can write it! (Asking for code recommendations is off-topic for Stack Overflow, though.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For sure it is possible. Why would we need any module, modules are just codes like ours.

```py
def encrypt(text_to_encrypt, string, step):
    s = "" # we will add our slices of string into this
    i, j = 0, step # we will use i and j for slicing "string", which we will hide our message inside
    for c in text_to_encrypt: # c will be the character
        s += string[i: j] + c # add strings to "s"
        i = j # make i equal to j, so we will be get the next slice of "string" in the next time
        j += step # increase j by step
        if j > len(string): # if j is bigger than lenght of the string..
            i, j = 0, step # reset indexes
    return s # return value

print(encrypt("IPHONE", "JZIANEUDHCZOANZ", 3)) # JZIIANEPUDHHCZOOANZNJZIE
```

Comment: `encrypt` function has a ``step`` parameter. You can just change it.